# PHP utf8 intval

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, utf

I  am reading a UTF8 file and storing data read from file in an array. However, when using that data in mysql queries, I am getting problems.
I thought that I will convert all int values explicitly using intval(..) before using them. But intval(utf8string) is giving me zero.

Following code gives unexpected output:

```
 //.....
 var_dump($data[10]);
 echo '|' . $data[10] . "|\n";  
 echo '|' . bin2hex($data[10]) . "|\n";
 echo '|' . utf8_decode($data[10]) . "|\n";
 echo '|' . intval(utf8_decode($data[10])) . "|\n";
 echo '|' . intval($data[10]). "|\n"; exit
 //.....
```

Output:

```
string(15) "2240000"
|2240000|
|003200320034003000300030003000|
|2240000|
|0|
|0|
```

Any idea how to get correct intval from such data?

Comment: I don't understand how you'd get the results you're seeing.  Can you add the result of `var_dump($data[10]);` to the example?

Comment: Show us a `bin2hex($data[10])`. There should be no problem with digits encoded in UTF-8, since they're identical to ASCII.

Comment: I have added output of both functions above.

Comment: Your string definately contains non-printable characters at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your string is encoded in **UTF-16**, not UTF-8.

Either change something about where you get the data from, or convert the encoding:

```
$data[10] = iconv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', $data[10])
```

Comment: In this, I get an NOTICE:PHP Notice:  iconv(): Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string in....
And the string gets corrupted.

Comment: @user You have a trailing `NUL` byte, and the string doesn't start with a BOM, which is required for a UTF-16 string. Where does this string come from and how do you get it into this array?